# Spring4 Security - how to secure restful api with access token only, no login required

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, token

I have met a seemly easy, but actual pretty difficult situation for me, hope you can help.
WE need to provide secured rest api, but we have difference service, for example, authentication service, execution service. I now need to secure execution service. 
I am using spring4 boot to boost, it seemed natural that using spring security, and then provide a customer userdetail service,but then when I start implement it, I met this big problem.
ExecutionService is not responsible for login purpose, so it won't provide a login form and consequently, it won't save token at all. What it needs to do is only checking header info, if it sees token in the header, it will use some decode algorithm to decode that token and then check if user is qualified to continue to not.
In all the posts on line regarding spring security, it all require a token storage, that means, user login first and then save token in memory, and then when user comes again, just check that token.
Can anyone help me to figure out, 
1) how to use spring security to check request header info;
2) when see token in header, use a customized function to check validity of that header and then authenticate the user based on the checking result?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into oauth2. Specifically, check out spring security oauth: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/. You could set a token on login for the browser to use and your api services to validate against.

Comment: especially with spring session it's often easier to just use the session key and let it validate in redis